# Netbeans: move a text file into dist folder when compiling

Tags: compilation, netbeans-7

I have a text file (let's say `textfile.txt`) stored in the project folder in *Netbeans 7.3*, e.g.

```
project folder
  textfile.txt
  src
    package
    package.subpackage
      MyClass.java
```

When I compile I get a `dist` folder where the *jar* file is put in, e.g.

```
project folder
  textfile.txt
  dist
    MyProject.jar
  src
    package
    package.subpackage
      MyClass.java
```

How can I edit the `build.xml` file to make the file `textfile.txt` being copied under `dist` folder?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Edit the "-post-compile" target inside the `build.xml` as follows:

```
<target name="-post-compile">
    <copy file="textfile.txt" todir="${dist.dir}"/>        
</target>
```

Comment: And what happens if I want to put the file in a subfolder?

Comment: Try with `todir="${dist.dir}/subfoldername"`

Comment: Do you know how to solve [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372374/move-a-text-file-into-target-folder-when-compiling-a-maven-project)?

Comment: Well, yes! I just posted the answer.

Comment: For others coming from google, see here to expand this great answer to cover wildcards: http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/samples-ant-copy-task

Comment: @JeanValjean I'm getting the error that `<Path>${dist.dir}\resources does not exist`. Please help.

Comment: @max777 you should open a new question and post the whole pom and project structure. Otherwise I cannot help!