# Move a text file into target folder when compiling a Maven project

Tags: maven, build-automation, netbeans-7

I have a slight different version of [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16356849/netbeans-move-a-text-file-into-dist-folder-when-compiling) that I made recently.
I have a **Maven** project under **Netbeans 7.3**, which doesn't have any `build.xml` file to configure building options, while there is the `pom.xml` that I use to import other libraries. Now, I have a text file (let's say `textfile.txt`) stored in the project folder in *Netbeans 7.3*, e.g.

```
project folder
  textfile.txt
  src
    package
    package.subpackage
      MyClass.java
```

When I compile I get a `target` folder where the *jar* file is put in, e.g.

```
project folder
  textfile.txt
  target
    classes
    generated-sources
    ....etc
    test-classes
    MyProject.jar
  src
    package
    package.subpackage
      MyClass.java
```

How can I make the file textfile.txt being copied under target folder when I compile the Maven project?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

A first way is to put the files into `src/main/resources` that is the folder devoted to store the complied resources, i.e. the resources included into the jar file (e.g. images for the icons).

If you need to make the config file to be distributed with the jar, but separated by it, you must edit the `pom.xml` file. A possible answer is the to add the following plugin between the `<plugins>` and `</plugins>` tags.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <echo>Using env.test.properties</echo>
                    <copy file="textfile.txt" tofile="${basedir}/target/textfile.txt"/>
                    </tasks>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Moreover, as you can read [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html) you can also import all the resources from an "input" directory to an "output" directory inside target by using the dedicated plugin, e.g.:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <executions>
         <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <!-- here the phase you need -->
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
               <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
               <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/output</outputDirectory>
               <resources>          
                    <resource>
                        <directory>input</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
               </resources>              
            </configuration>            
        </execution>
     </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure that the first plugin is used right, but works fine.

Comment: Awesome, this helps out a lot, thank you JeanValjean!

Answer (score 37):

The simplest way, to use some resource as I know (additional information about resources configuration you can find here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/):

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <!-- your plugins, including or not maven-resource-plugin -->
  </plugins>
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <filtering>true</filtering><!-- if it is neccessary -->
      <directory>${project.basedir}</directory><!-- from -->
      <targetPath>${project.build.directory}</targetPath><!-- to -->
      <includes><!-- what -->
        <include>textfile.txt</include>
      </includes>
    </resource>
  </resources>
</build>
```

Comment: How to make sure that textfile.txt is getting copied to jar file as well?

Comment: i got it. Thank you.

Comment: This was just too easy.  Thanks!

Comment: This should be the accept answer, really the simplest way.

Comment: Can I set a list of targets? In my case I need to copy to multiple targets.

Comment: This monkeys with Maven defaults, which may be okay given the use case. However, it operates in the `process-resources` phase of the build lifecycle. This orchestrates at the file system, before the packaging (JAR/WAR/etc.) level.

Answer (score 9):

For building my setting files and updating production this worked for me:

```
<build>
<resources>  
   <resource>
       <directory>${project.basedir}</directory><!-- from -->
       <targetPath>${project.build.directory}</targetPath><!-- to -->
       <includes><!-- what -->
          <include>**/*.properties</include>
       </includes>
    </resource> 
</resources>
</build>
```

Comment: Only works if you explicitly call  `mvn resources:resources` right?

Comment: @djangofan No, it works all the time. It's part of the POM build descriptor, not a plugin. However, it changes default Maven behaviors for any build from this POM.

Answer (score 5):

To have an absolute control of the output of your build you can use the "Apache Maven Assembly Plugin". You can define pretty much everything (format, subfolders...).

> The Assembly Plugin for Maven is primarily intended to allow users to aggregate the project output along with its dependencies, modules, site documentation, and other files into a single distributable archive.

[More info](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/)

You have to install the plugin in your pom file:

```
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <descriptors>
                <descriptor>src/main/assembly/yourassembly.xml</descriptor>
            </descriptors>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>

<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>x.x</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/yourassembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                    <phase>package</phase> <!-- append to the packaging phase. -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal> <!-- goals == mojos -->
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

In your case the descriptor "yourassembly.xml" would be as follows:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
  <id>yourassembly</id>
  <formats>
    <format>tar.gz</format>
    <format>dir</format>
  </formats>
  <fileSets>

    <fileSet>
      <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
      <includes>
        <include>README*</include>
        <include>LICENSE*</include>
        <include>NOTICE*</include>
      </includes>
      <useDefaultExcludes>true</useDefaultExcludes>
    </fileSet>

    <fileSet>
      <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
      <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
      <includes>
        <include>*.jar</include>
      </includes>
    </fileSet>

    <fileSet>
      <directory>${basedir}</directory>
      <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
      <includes>
        <include>textfile.txt</include>
      </includes>
    </fileSet>

    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
            <unpack>false</unpack>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>

  </fileSets>

</assembly>
```